# High Resolution Capture and Encoding

Tags: directshow, encoder

I'm using two custom push filters to inject audio and video (uncompressed RGB) into a DirectShow graph. I'm making a video capture application, so I'd like to encode the frames as they come in and store them in a file.

Up until now, I've used the ASF Writer to encode the input to a WMV file, but it appears the renderer is too slow to process high resolution input (such as 1920x1200x32). At least, `FillBuffer()` seems to only be able to process around 6-15 FPS, which obviously isn't fast enough.

I've tried increasing the `cBuffers` count in `DecideBufferSize()`, but that only pushes the problem to a later point, of course.

What are my options to speed up the process? What's the right way to do live high res encoding via DirectShow? I eventually want to end up with a WMV video, but maybe that has to be a post-processing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have great answers posted here to your question: [High resolution capture and encoding too slow](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/31a81f50-a158-463a-9e8c-669b78c173f9). The task is too complex for the CPU in your system, which is just not fast enough to perform realtime video encoding in the configuration you set it to work.

Comment: Yep, the replies happened to come in faster on MSDN than here (that's a first :) Out of curiosity, do you have an answer to the last question I put in there (the one about the framerate)?

Comment: The CPU intensive part is obviously the encoder. And it's up to encoder to utilize multiple CPU cores to process data and come up with least possible processing time - there is little you can do tweaking just software settings if the encoder is unable to get you compressed content on time. The most perhaps obvious to is lower encoding complexity - this way the output comes faster with all other parameters left the same.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the follow-up question in my latest post, i.e. the one about timing the capture of individual frames. Should I always try to hit the video's target mark, i.e. every 1/30 sec from the first frame's timestamp, or should I just go 1/30 seconds from the last time I captured a frame (assuming I'm capturing with 30 FPS)?

Comment: Given the encoder is unable to compress in real time, what exactly you are trying to achieve? (a) find another mode less computationally intensive (b) reduce frame rate (c) accumulate raw data and compress full fragment, slower than in real-time?

Comment: The question I ask at the end of the thread you linked to above isn't about pushing frames through the encoder at a fast pace, but instead about capturing the frames. Since I don't control the rate of frames in the application I get them from, I'm trying to capture frames at the best time possible time interval to make the encoded video look as smooth as possible.

Comment: As I mention in the thread, I'm using an error tolerance to try and hit the capture mark as best as I can, but I'm wondering if the resulting video will look better if I always try to use the capture "beat" based on the timestamp on the very first frame OR if I'll have more luck capturing always ~1/30 seconds later than last time I captured a frame.

Comment: The problem you will be dealing with is that some frames are much longer to compress than other, so it will have to take this into account when choosing best frame rate. I would say that if you want to do it automatically, you will have to keep a history of encoding times, per frame and have some average on hands to estimate effective compression rate and then decide whether to keep or discard input frame. Dealing on the edge of CPU possibilities, the most accurate perhaps will be to find the amount you can compress per second, and set camera capture rate at some 850-90% of this amount.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4996/discussion-between-dreijer-and-roman-r)